# BitmapSource.CopyPixels -what's a good value for stride?

Tags: wpf, image

I'm trying to get the pixel data from a WPF `BitmapSource` object. As I understand, this can be accomplished by calling its `CopyPixels` method. This method needs a stride parameter, which I don't know how to obtain. As far as I know, stride is value that's used when stepping in the array during reading or copying. What would be an appropriate stride value for any BitmapSource?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use stride = pixel_size * image_width value. For example, for RGBA bitmap with 100 pixel width, stride = 400.

Some applications may require special line alignment. For example, Windows GDI bitmaps require 32-bits line alignment. In this case, for RGB bitmap with width = 33, stride value 33*3=99 should be changed to 100, to have 32-bits line alignment in destination array.

Generally, you should know destination array requirements. In there are no special requirements, use default pixel_size * image_width.

Comment: So I guess it's pixel size in bytes then?

Comment: Yes, this is pixel size in bytes. BitmapSource.Format property returns PixelFormat structure. For example, pixel size for Bgr32 is 4, for Bgr24 - 3, for Gray8 - 1 etc. Copying bitmap data to array, you need to know exactly resulting array structure, and it is defined by Format property.

Comment: I personnally use code like this to have 32-bit alignment (so that I can create a System.Drawing.Bitmap from the wpf image) :

`var stride = width * (bitmapSource.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);            
stride += (4 - stride % 4);`

Comment: Oups, there is a bug above. If the width is already 32-bit aligned, I add an extra 4 bytes to the stride... so the working code should be

`var stride = width * (bitmapSource.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8); 
var mod = stride % 4;
if (mod != 0) stride += 4 - mod;`

Comment: @odalet - actually, your stride computation maybe ok with GDI+, but it's wrong with WPF BitmapSource. With BitmapSource.CopyPixels, you must not add the 32-bit padding. Alex's answer is correct, with WPF it's just PixelWidth*BitsPerPixel

Comment: Can 
stride = image.PixelWidth * (image.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8
be a good calculation in WPF?

Answer (score 3):

```
var stride = ((bitmapSource.PixelWidth * bitmapSource.Format.BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32) * 4;
```

or

```
var stride = ((bitmapSource.PixelWidth * bitmapSource.Format.BitsPerPixel + 31) >> 5) << 2;
```