# RenderTargetBitmap save raw data to disk

Tags: wpf, bytebuffer, rendertargetbitmap

I have a hight fps stream of RenderTargetBitmap's
I want to save them to disk to process them later, I do not want to encode them to Png, bmp or what ever, I want to save the raw byte buffer.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [CopyPixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616043.aspx) method to get the raw pixels. Then just write it out like any other data. More information on getting the pixels can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881857/bitmapsource-copypixels-whats-a-good-value-for-stride).

But really, you could save it out as a Tiff with no compression and get the same results.