# How to Convert Wpf BitmapSource to byte[] in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF Image to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553611/wpf-image-to-byte)

[Relative to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553611/wpf-image-to-byte) I have a BitmapSource image obtained by capturing image from webcam.How can i convert it to byte[] in C#

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got solution

```
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        //encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
        encoder.QualityLevel = 100;          
       // byte[] bit = new byte[0];
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {               
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
            encoder.Save(stream);
            byte[] bit = stream.ToArray(); 
            stream.Close();               
        }
```

Comment: You seem to be adding two bitmap frames. Any reason for that overhead? Also, why are you instantiating an empty byte array, only to overwrite it later?

Comment: @Mathias He's not adding two bitmap frames. He's creating a bitmap frame, adding it to the encoder's frames. He's then saving the encoder to the memory stream. He then converts the stream to a byte array. It is overhead, sure, but not any that can really be gotten around. Calling stream.Close(), though, is superfluous. The whole point of the 'using' block is to dispose of (which includes a .Close() call) the stream.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [BitmapSource.CopyPixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616043.aspx) method to copy the raw data out to a byte array. The stride parameter is the number of bytes in each image row. A 100-pixels wide RGBA image will have a stride of 100*4=400 bytes.

Check this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881857/bitmapsource-copypixels-whats-a-good-value-for-stride) for the stride parameter and how it behaves for different image types