# Loading remote image and writing it from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to return an image from a controller and be able to apply my own filters on it.

I created a controller and would like it to `return Content(Img.BinaryData,"image/jpeg");`

A view is not needed.

I'm using **[DynamicImage](http://dynamicimage.apphb.com/)** plugin to get a remote image and do some filters on it, but it returns a [`System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object.

Here is the furthest I got, but I'm trying to return it as binary data:

```
using SoundInTheory.DynamicImage.Sources;   

var composition = new Composition();
ImageLayer layer = new ImageLayer { Source = new RemoteImageSource { Url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" } };
composition.Layers.Add(layer);

GeneratedImage generatedImage = composition.GenerateImage();

var Img = generatedImage.Image; // returns System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap

return Content(Img.ToString(),"image/jpeg");
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var Img = generatedImage.Image

var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
var bmFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(Img);
encoder.Frames.Add(bmFrame);
encoder.QualityLevel = 100;

var res = new byte[0];

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{               
    encoder.Frames.Add(bmFrame);
    encoder.Save(stream);
    res = stream.ToArray(); 
    stream.Close();
}

return File(res, "image/jpeg");
```

(The BitmapSource to byte[] conversion is taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11085124/1625737)